# Eclipse refactoring: move method inside collaborator

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I have the following scenario:

```
public class Controller {

  private ModelRepository repository;

  public int getModelCount() {
    int count = 0;
    List<Model> models = repository.getModels();

    for (Model model : models) {
      if (model.somePredicate()) {
        count++;
      }
    }

    return count;
  }
}
```

Now, I'd like to move the `getModelCount` method inside `ModelRepository` by using some automated Eclipse refactoring so that I end up with this in the controller:

```
public class Controller {

  private ModelRepository repository;

  public int getModelCount() {
    repository.getModelCount();
  }
}
```

Is this possible in Eclipse Indigo? If yes, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a single-hop refactor, but you can do it in two.

First, highlight the contents of the `getModelCount()` method and do a `refactor->extract method`, calling the new method something like `countModels`.

Secondly, do a `refactor->move` on the new `countModels()` method, selecting the `repository` field as the destination.

This will leave you with a method on the `ModelRepository` called `countModels` rather than `getModelCount`. For completeness you could do a `refactor->rename` on this, but I prefer `countModels` anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems the `refactor->move` operation works directly on that method. My problem was that the type of the `repository` field was an interface, instead of a class. That's why Eclipse had problems moving it.